# How to get mail interceptors working with postgeapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postageapp

I am using rails v3.2.13 and the postageapp gem to manage my email templates. I am following the [railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3) for mail interceptors but they don't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging the postageapp gem showed that it was by-passing the interceptor method and also not applying the `perform_deliveries` flag.

The postageapp interceptor is also slightly different to the Mail interceptor as postageapp passes a `Request` object instead of a Mail `Message` object. This is an example of a postageapp interceptor:

```
class DevelopmentPostageappInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(postageapp_msg)
    postageapp_msg.arguments["headers"][:subject] = "[#{postageapp_msg.arguments["recipients"]}] #{postageapp_msg.arguments["headers"][:subject]}"
    postageapp_msg.arguments["recipients"] = "test@example.com"
    # postageapp_msg.perform_deliveries = false
  end
end
```

Hope this helps anyone wanting to use rails3 interceptors with postageapp :)

**EDIT:** this is now available in the [postageapp-ruby gem](https://github.com/postageapp/postageapp-ruby) v1.0.23